# Objective-C 2.0 is not working in GNUstep

Tags: objective-c, gcc, syntax, gnustep

```
[GNUStep installers]
gnustep-system-0.24.2-setup.exe
gnustep-core-0.25.0-setup.exe
gnustep-devel-1.1.1-setup.exe
gnustep-cairo-0.22.1-setup.exe
```

I installed them to windows 7.
But, it is not able to use Objective-C 2.0 syntax.
Example, `@property`, `@synthesize`, `assign`, and so on.

And, I want to use `CFSocket`, but `CoreFoundation` was not supported.

Comment: If you have access to a Mac, you might want to try cross-compiling with Cocotron instead. Objective-C 2.0 and CoreFoundation both work great there.

Answer (score 4):

According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C version 2.0 is only available in the Apple modification to the gnu compiler.

CoreFoundation is also an Apple framework/library, so you won't have much joy there.

Comment: This is not entirely true because support for ObjC-2.0 is in development. See the answer of ericwa (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562658/objective-c-2-0-is-not-working-in-gnustep/3580604#3580604)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, Objective-C 2 features aren't available in the current Windows release of GNUstep. (They are in development versions of Clang, GNUstep, and the GNUstep runtime, but this combination is not yet released).

There are more details here: http://wiki.gnustep.org/index.php/ObjC2_FAQ

As you noted, CF functions are not present. NSStream can be used for socket communication (+getStreamsToHost:port:inputStream:outputStream:), but I'm not sure if it would work for what you want to do.

Comment: Is it possible to use the yet unreleased version? Can you possibly provide a link for those who want to try this out?

Answer (score 0):

Core Foundation is not part of GNUstep unfortunately.  However, Apple does have a cut down Open Source distribution called [CFLite](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-550/) which looks to contain [CFSocket](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-550/CFSocket.h).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this [similar Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150675/how-does-one-use-obj-c-2-0-with-gnustep) post helps. It talks about setting up GNUstep with libobjc2 on Ubuntu but might also work on Windows.

It also mentions the [libobjc2 FAQ](http://wiki.gnustep.org/index.php/ObjC2_FAQ) where you might get some answers to your question.