# How does one use Obj-C 2.0 with GNUstep?

Tags: objective-c, ubuntu, makefile, gnustep

I'm aware of the existence of libobjc2, and I gather that I'll need to use clang rather than GCC, but I can't find any basic instructions of what's different about the compilation process.

Can anyone give **explicit, step-by-step instructions** on acquiring, configuring, compiling, and using GNUstep with **Objective-C 2.0 in Ubuntu**?

Comment: I still haven't found an answer to this, but in the meantime, I've switched to Cocotron, and Obj-C 2.0 works just great there (along with NSXMLDocument and some other things I found lacking in GNUstep). Of course, it requires cross-compiling from a Mac. :(

Answer (score 2):

Since the [GNUStep ObjC2 FAQ](http://wiki.gnustep.org/index.php/ObjC2_FAQ) has already been referenced, I'll assume you've had a look. I would like to point this out, however:

> For more advanced features, currently only supported if you compile with Clang, you will need the GNUstep runtime. This is not currently considered production ready. It should work as a drop-in replacement for the GCC runtime, but some of the advanced features are not well-tested.

[The FAQ](http://wiki.gnustep.org/index.php/ObjC2_FAQ) also calls out the following:

> If you are using a recent version of GCC to compile your code then you should have a copy of the Objective-C runtime library that came with your compiler.
>
> If you compile with the -fobjc-nonfragile-abi flag then you will use the new ABI. This is only supported with the GNUstep runtime. This adds:
>
> - Property introspection
> - Introspection on optional protocol methods
> - Non-fragile instance variables
> - Forwarding proxy support

So, if you're looking for older functionality via GCC, [this tutorial](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1338278) would do the job nicely, as would [this one.](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1064045) You've explicitly called out that you're looking to do this with the functionality provided by Clang (via *libobjc2*), which has its own bed of documentation.

[Obtaining a release of Clang and getting set up](http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html) seems fairly cut and dried. The [LLVM Getting Started](http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html) document is exceptionally robust (full documentation archive [here](http://llvm.org/docs/)), which should provide insight into getting the backend set up and compiling properly. Some additional insight into the expected build procedure can be found [here](http://groups.google.com/group/gnu.gnustep.discuss/browse_thread/thread/aff1ce44eb46ec4/62f79e3e4ee49603?lnk=gst#62f79e3e4ee49603).

However, compiling an Objective-C application in Clang seems extremely underdocumented and untested at the time of this writing. As features become available and the codebase stabilizes, I imagine more user documentation will go live.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've now successfully compiled libobjc2 (I had to compile clang from source to get libobjc2 to compile, strangely), and I've even managed to compile gnustep-base and link with libobjc2. Unfortunately, any usage of NSObject (which is real rare ;)) causes a segfault. I think maybe GNUstep is just not ready for normal people to use yet (although word is the entire Etoilé project dev team is using libobjc2 successfully; grr).

Answer (score -1):

According to the [GNUstep Wiki](http://wiki.gnustep.org/index.php/ObjC2_FAQ), you need just need to compile your code with `-fblocks` and `-fobjc-nonfragile-abi`. Then you just use the language features in your code.

Comment: I believe the process is much more complicated than that. Google suggests that GNUstep make and GNUstep base must be recompiled with libobjc2 in mind.